# Meizu MX4 PRO - Ubuntu

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

I would like to buy the Meizu MX4 PRO (not the MX4 Ubuntu edition)([this one](http://www.meizu.com/en/products/mx4pro/summary.html)) and I have a question.

I read that in normal MX4 (not pro) you can boot Ubuntu, but will I be able to boot it on MX4 pro? If not, I will buy the normal (non-pro) mx4, but all Ubuntu editions are sold :( does anyone know of a source where can I buy this one? All responses are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> I read that in normal mx4 (not pro) you can boot ubuntu, but will I be able to boot it on mx4 pro?

No. All supported devices are listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)

> does anyone know the source where can i buy this one?

The MX4 Ubuntu edition seems to be sold out at the moment (January 2016).

Meizu has the same hardware in both versions of MX4 (Android and Ubuntu touch), so in theory you could flash Ubuntu touch on an Android version.
There are some instructions on how to do this on the net e.g. [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/xda-external-link/flash-ubuntu-touch-on-meizu-mx4/). However, since this will void your warranty and is not guaranteed to work, it is something you might not want to try on a new phone.

Comment: If you do buy an andriod one and then flush it, it would be very interesting to know how you got on. It seems like a lot of people still want to get their hands on the currently out of stock Pro 5. So if this works it could be a good way to go forward with a phone that has a nice spec. I would personally be very keen to know how this goes.

Answer (score 1):

This may be another option for you as I read that the MX6 is soon to be released with Ubuntu [The Meizu MX6 Made Official, Ubuntu Edition ‘Coming Soon’](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/meizu-mx6-official-announcement-specs)